# Toolbar dropdown menu is not closing on click of toolbar button or clicked outside of tinymce editor

Tags: tinymce, text-editor, tinymce-6

Toolbar dropdown menu is not closing on click of toolbar button or clicked outside of editor. how to fix the issue.

NOTE : i'm using this version of tinymce -> `tinymce": "^6.8.3`
below is the configuration for tinymce editor-

```js
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    placeholder: "Content",
    min_height: 300,
    promotion: false,
    branding: false,
    plugins: 'link lists anchor autoresize emoticons preview code',
    toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic underline strikethrough superscript subscript| forecolor backcolor | \
        alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | \
        bullist numlist outdent indent hr| \
        link emoticons | FileManager | customUppercase customLowercase',
    menubar: 'format',
    menu: {
        format: { title: 'Format', items: 'styles fontsize align lineheight | removeformat' },
    }
});
```

## Screenshot & expected behavior

[image]